# QPyNullVariant not recognized outside of QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I'm getting an error about an operation involving a QPyNullVariant:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'QPyNullVariant' and 'float'
```

I wanted to put a check into my code to skip these values. However, my IDE (Eclipse) [and more over the terminal Python interface] doesn't recognize this as part of the PyQt4.QtCore module whereas it seems fine within QGIS. I have updated all my packages and restarted my computer.

```
import PyQt4.QtCore as pyqt
import sys
print(sys.version)    #1
print(pyqt.__file__)  #2
pyqt.QPyNullVariant   #3
```

in all cases this produces the following out put for 1 and 2:

```
2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2]

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so
```

However in Eclipse (with PyDev) and in the terminal interpreter the call to PyQt module for a QPyNullVariant attribute fails:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QPyNullVariant'
```

whereas in the QGIS python interpreter you get:

```
<class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QPyNullVariant'>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Further debugging and a try/except show that it evaluates as equal to `None` which is good for a simple test, but... I'm still puzzled.